# Why can't I connect to my Node? (on MacBook)

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node

I just got a Bitcoin Core node running on my computer.

The next thing I wanted to do is connect Sparrow or Specter to it. But none of them are able to connect.

What can I do to make sure it's not my network settings? I'm not super knowledgable about this stuff, so talk to me like I'm 10.

Appreciate your help. please and thanks.

Thanks
Doug

Comment: Are you running macOS on your MacBook? If so, have you checked your firewall configuration? E.g. no "block all incoming connections" configuration key...